# Windows Phone 8 maps - licence uncertainty

Tags: windows-phone-8, maps

I plan developing Windows Phone 8 map application and think of using standard wp8 maps (Nokia) and map controls. It will be a fleet maagement/customers' devices location control application.

May I use standard maps used in wp8 and classes such as Microsoft.Phone.Maps, Microsoft.Phone.Maps.Controls?

On the first side, on the page
http://developer.nokia.com/lumia/nokia-apis/mapping
there is info:

> Developers can use the APIs and library for any applications published
>   in Windows Phone Store.
>   The Windows Phone 8 Maps API and HERE
>   launchers are available free of charge for all developers.

But on the other side, when you enter "full terms and conditions" there is point 3 "Use Restrictions" where we can find like

> You may  not:  (...)
>
> - use the Mapping APIs for business asset tracking, fleet management, or dispatch;
> - use the Mapping APIs in connection with any internal business application which (a) is  directly related to the operation of your
>     core business or the core business of your  customers, and (b) the
>     sole users of such application are your employees, contactors or 
>     customers;

**Does it mean my fleet maagement/customers' devices location control application can't use any Microsoft maps control code?** (even with tiles from other source like OSM) If so, what are the other options/libraries?

Answer (score 0):

Your application CAN use the Windows Phone 8 Maps API, but CAN'T use the Mapping APIS. Those are two different APIs: the first one is what you need to use (show points, routes, etc.), the second one is to create a map image, I mean, create roads, avenues, etc.